# How to make xml parser ignore invalid characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing, lxml

I am using python module lxml to parse xml files. However, some of the xml files contain invalid characters such as ® . Due to this, I am getting following error.

> lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
>
> Bytes: 0xAE 0x0A 0x53 0x6F, line 45, column 91

-> Removing the character solves the problem.

I cannot tell the data provider to provide me xml without such character.
To avoid duplication, I have tried following solution from stack overflow and it gave me same error.

```
parsed_doc = etree.parse(u, etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8', ns_clean=True, recover=True))
```

How do I ignore/escape such characters?

Comment: Looks like your data is actually encoded in ISO-8859-1.  Why not try specifying that as the encoding instead?

Comment: Thanks, I will try and see if that solves the issue. the top xml tag has utf-8 as encoding attribute. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>. Does it mean there is a mistake from the data provider?

Comment: 0xAE 0x0A 0x53 0x6F means "®\nSo" in Latin-1. Is the XML document using only latin1 or does it mixes latin1 and utf-8 ? In all cases you should at least tell the provider, even if you solve it your side.

Comment: It mixes latin1 and utf-8. I will tell my provider about the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Try put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*`in your .py file. Solved a lot of utf-errors for me.

Comment: @Ola do you want me to put that in the top of module that is parsing the xml?

Comment: @jwodder  Most of files are actually encoded in utf-8 except few. Therefore, I whenever I caught the wrong encoding error. I detected the encoding using
encoding = chardet.detect(content)['encoding'] and called my parser with the appropriate encoding. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: @paris_serviola Yes. Like under `#!/usr/bin/env python`. But you seem to have fixed it already.

Comment: strictly speaking, your xml file is still not well-formed... my view is that xml parser should detect encoding automatically from the xml file... specifying the encoding manually violates the XML spec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @jwodder, the xml file was not encoded with utf-8 encoding even though it had utf-8 as encoding attribute.  . I changed my encoding params to ISO-8859-1 in lxml parser.

```
parsed_doc = etree.parse(u, etree.XMLParser(encoding='ISO-8859-1', ns_clean=True, recover=True))
```

It worked perfectly.